# I've been trying to integrate mgt-react components to my App but it seems to conflict with other packages

Tags: reactjs, npm, azure-ad-msal, parcel

This is the error I get when including mtg-react like this:

`import { Login } from "@microsoft/mgt-react";`

```
components.ts:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: PersonCardInteraction
       at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
       at components.ts:25
       at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
       at Object.parcelRequire.../node_modules/@microsoft/mgt-components/dist/es6/components/components.js../mgt-agenda/mgt-agenda (components.ts:25)
       at newRequire (App.d36a57b6.js:47)
       at localRequire (App.d36a57b6.js:53)
       at Object.parcelRequire.../node_modules/@microsoft/mgt-components/dist/es6/index.js../components/components (index.ts:8)
       at newRequire (App.d36a57b6.js:47)
       at localRequire (App.d36a57b6.js:53)
       at Object.parcelRequire.../node_modules/@microsoft/mgt-react/dist/es6/generated/react.js.../Mgt (react.ts:166)
```

Comment: I followed the steps [shared at the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/use-toolkit-with-react) and it worked for me. Can you validate you're doing the same or different?

Comment: Yes, I've reinstalled everything to make sure I'm doing the same thing and still get an error when I try to add the <Login /> component